# React Map function only returns data from last index Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have an array of json objects and when I display them in a table the data matches. But if I now want to delete one of the objects it does not work. Because only the data of the last index is given to the delete function.

## React Component

```
import { Box, Checkbox, IconButton, Typography } from "@mui/joy";
import { Player } from "../utils/interfaces";
import OpenInNewIcon from "@mui/icons-material/OpenInNew";
import React from "react";
import DeleteButton from "../components/DeleteButton";
import AlertDialog from "../components/AlertDialog";
import { deletePlayer } from "../utils/database";
import { Order, compare, getComparator, handleDelete, stableSort } from "./methods";

interface contentProps {
  players: Player[];
  setPlayers: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Player[]>>;
  selected: readonly string[];
  setSelected: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<readonly string[]>>;
  filteredPlayers: Player[];
  setFilteredPlayers: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Player[]>>;
  searchValue: String;
}

function ExportButton() {
  return (
    <IconButton size="sm">
      <OpenInNewIcon fontSize="small" />
    </IconButton>
  );
}

const PlayerTableContent: React.FC<contentProps> = ({
  players,
  setPlayers,
  selected,
  setSelected,
  filteredPlayers,
  setFilteredPlayers,
  searchValue
}) => {
  const [alertOpen, setAlertOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      {stableSort(searchValue ? filteredPlayers : players, compare).map((player, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td style={{ textAlign: "center", width: 120 }}>
            <Checkbox
              size="sm"
              checked={selected.includes(player.id)}
              color={selected.includes(player.id) ? "primary" : undefined}
              onChange={(event) => {
                setSelected((ids) =>
                  event.target.checked
                    ? ids.concat(player.id)
                    : ids.filter((itemId) => itemId !== player.id)
                );
              }}
              slotProps={{ checkbox: { sx: { textAlign: "left" } } }}
              sx={{ verticalAlign: "text-bottom" }}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <Typography level="body-xs">{player.id.substring(0, 8)}...</Typography>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Typography level="body-xs">{player.name}</Typography>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Typography level="body-xs">{player.sirname}</Typography>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Typography level="body-xs">{player.clazz}</Typography>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Box sx={{ display: "flex", gap: 2, alignItems: "flex-end", justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
              <ExportButton />
              <DeleteButton onClick={() => setAlertOpen(true)} />
              <AlertDialog open={alertOpen} setOpen={setAlertOpen} onAcceptClick={() => handleDelete(player.id, filteredPlayers, players, setPlayers, setFilteredPlayers)} />
            </Box>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default PlayerTableContent
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work, as it has always worked fine until now, but since I added the sort function it no longer works. And even when I reverted to the previous version it no longer works. I don't know if I'm just being silly or if I've broken it.

Comment: You need to clarify what "does not work" means; is it not rendering? Are you getting errors in the console? etc.

Comment: Just before the `return()` of your component, put `console.log("table data is", stableSort(searchValue ? filteredPlayers : players, compare))` and see in your browser's JS console what the data is that your code is about to display.

Comment: the problem is that the handleDelete function always only gives the id of the last player. so not the id of the player currently displayed. but the data is always displayed correctly.